# why typedef the same identifier

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Is there any benefit in typedef-ing the same identifier as shown below:

```
typedef struct Struct_name
{
  //something....
} Struct_name;
```

I have come across this style mostly with `struct`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ already allows you to refer to `struct Struct_name` as `Struct_name`. But it has a special rule that permits this alias to declare the same identifier to `Struct_name` via typedef.

The reason is C compatibility. In C, `struct Struct_name` can only be referred to as `Struct_name` when that `typedef` is present. So what you see allows one to put this structure in a header that is included by both C and C++ code. Thus letting both code bases refer to the type as both `struct Struct_name` and `Struct_name`.

Comment: Is this used only with struct?

Comment: @ChiefA - It can be used with any declaration that can be understood by both a C and a C++ compiler. So `union` and `enum` too.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. SO doesn't allow me to accept an answer within 5 min.!!or maybe 15 min considering the time of posting the question.

Comment: @ChiefA - NP. I was happy to help